# Select latest NOT NULL values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have table with many statuses like

```
Id | Date | IsEnabled | IsUpdated | IsDuplicate | IsSuspended | ...
```

Statuses (IsEnabled, IsUpdated, IsDuplicate, IsSuspended...) are nullable bits.

I need to select the latest (but not greater then some input date) not nullable statuses from this table. In case some status has `NULL` value then select previous not nullable value.

I've create select to select only latest values and can't understand how to get previous not nullable values.

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  cbs.*, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cbs.Id ORDER BY cbs.[Date] DESC)
    FROM    [dbo].CompanyBusinessStatus cbs
    WHERE cbs.[Date] <= @inputDate
)

SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

I'm using MS SQL 2016

---

Data Example :

```
1 | 2017-01-01 | 1 | 0    | 0    | 0
_______________________________________
1 | 2017-01-03 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 1
_______________________________________
2 | 2017-01-03 | 1 | 1    | NULL | 0
_______________________________________
1 | 2017-01-05 | 0 | 1    | 0    | NULL
```

In case @inputDate is '2017-01-04' I need to select

```
   Id | IsEnabled | IsUpdated | IsDuplicate | IsSuspended 
_________________________________________________________
    1 | 1         | 0         | 0           | 1
_________________________________________________________
    2 | 1         | 1         | NULL        | 0
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also I think there is typo here, should be `0` not `1` for the last status of Id 1 in your desired output

Comment: @LONG, why? for Id = 1, IsEnabled and IsSuspended   should be 1 as row for date `2017-01-05` is skipped cause input date is less then date of this row. IsUpdated  and IsDuplicate should be taken from previous row, cause in latest row its values are NULL

Comment: did any of these answers resolve your question?

Comment: @MartinSmith, seems like your answer suits me the best. But requirements were changed, now I can't have NULL value in table, so I think my "start" query is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way ([demo](http://rextester.com/BUPKC43248)) would be

```
SELECT Id,
       IsEnabled = CAST(RIGHT(MAX(yyyymmdd + CAST(IsEnabled AS CHAR(1))), 1) AS BIT),
       IsUpdated = CAST(RIGHT(MAX(yyyymmdd + CAST(IsUpdated AS CHAR(1))), 1) AS BIT),
       IsDuplicate = CAST(RIGHT(MAX(yyyymmdd + CAST(IsDuplicate AS CHAR(1))), 1) AS BIT),
       IsSuspended = CAST(RIGHT(MAX(yyyymmdd + CAST(IsSuspended AS CHAR(1))), 1) AS BIT)
FROM   dbo.CompanyBusinessStatus cbs
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT FORMAT(Date, 'yyyyMMdd')) CA(yyyymmdd)
WHERE  cbs.[Date] <= @inputDate
GROUP  BY Id
```

If you have a covering index on `id` (or even if you don't but get a hash aggregate) this can produce a plan with no sort operations at all and may be significantly cheaper than Gordon's answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My other answer clearly misinterpreted the question.  Unfortunately, SQL Server only offers `FIRST_VALUE()` as a window function.  So, here is one method:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cbs.id,
       MAX(cbs.date) OVER (PARTITION BY cbs.id) as date,
       FIRST_VALUE(IsEnabled) OVER (PARTITION BY cbs.id ORDER BY (CASE WHEN IsEnabled IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END), cbs.date DESC) as isEnabled,
       FIRST_VALUE(IsUpdated) OVER (PARTITION BY cbs.id ORDER BY (CASE WHEN IsUpdated IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END), cbs.date DESC) as IsUpdated,
       . . .
FROM [dbo].CompanyBusinessStatus cbs
WHERE cbs.[Date] <= @inputDate ;
```

I'm not a fan of `SELECT DISTINCT` for this purpose, but it seems like the easiest way to express the logic.

ANSI SQL offers the `IGNORE NULL`s option for `FIRST_VALUE()` (and some other window functions).  However, SQL Server does not (yet) support this option.

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE` doens't skip `NULL`s in column

Answer (score 0):

For the query below, I think the `Order by` in the `ROW_NUMBER` will take the records with least `NULL` as the 1st one for your output.

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  cbs.*, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cbs.Id ORDER BY cbs.[Date] DESC, IsEnabled DESC,IsUpdated DESC,IsDuplicate DESC,IsSuspended DESC)
    FROM    [dbo].CompanyBusinessStatus cbs
    WHERE cbs.[Date] <= @inputDate
)

SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do what you want is to do a correlated sub-query for each of the "Status" columns.  It's a lot of SQL to write, and doesn't look very elegant, but it will definitely work in any version of SQL Server.

There might be a more elegant solution involving UNPIVOTing and then RE-PIVOTing, but I wouldn't bother going that route unless I had over 20 different "Status" columns.